# <c:catch> does not work with <fmt:parseNumber> JSTL 1.2

Tags: parsing, exception, jstl, tomcat7, catch-block

I'm implementing a simple JSP page using JSTL 1.2 (Apache Taglibs). The page does the following:

```
        <c:catch var="error">
            <fmt:parseNumber var="parsedNum" value="${param.num}" />
        </c:catch>
```

The HTML input element looks like this:

```
    <input type="text" name="num" size="3"/>
```

I'm aware that the input "12a" is permitted due to the way the parsing mechanism works. Nevertheless, I would like to catch completely wrong input, e.g., "aaa". Unfortunately, the thrown exception is not managed by `<c:catch>`, resulting in Tomcat 7 showing the whole stack trace.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post a testable page for us. For example, the following page works fine for me.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<c:catch var="error">
<fmt:parseNumber var="parsedNum" value="aaa" />
</c:catch>
${parsedNum}
${error}
```

Comment: My fault. The error was exactly after the `<c:catch>` block. The check: `<c:if test="${error}">...</c:if>` was obviously wrong. Sorry for wasting your time.